# Google Play Console Developer Monitoring errors

Tags: android, google-play, google-cloud-storage, monitoring, gsutil

Good afternoon.
1) A question about Google Play Console Developer. In the error reports, there is a "Crash Link" field, which contains a link to Crash Link. Is it possible to download in a report not a link, but a stack trace?
If not, is it possible to provide access to the stack trace to the user without giving it access to the Google Play Developer Console?

2) Is it possible in Google Play Developer Console reports to update statistics every 10 minutes for errors?
The task is to organize monitoring the operational monitoring of errors. If someone had to do this, tell me please options.

3) Is it possible to pull out the stack trace specified in the "Crash Link" field of the report using the gsutil utility?

Answer (score 1):

1) A question about Google Play Console Developer. In the error reports, there is a "Crash Link" field, which contains a link to Crash Link. Is it possible to download in a report not a link, but a stack trace? If not, is it possible to provide access to the stack trace to the user without giving it access to the Google Play Developer Console?

-> **Answer is yes** You can schedule a script on server to get crash report using gsutil. Add a user as Customer Service from google play store developer console and grand read only access to visibility ( You can grand app level access or all apps access ) - gs://pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/crashes
To get above link login to google play store developer console. Click on Report-> Crashes and ANR's.
Example of script - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en

2) Is it possible in Google Play Developer Console reports to update statistics every 10 minutes for errors? The task is to organize monitoring the operational monitoring of errors. If someone had to do this, tell me please options.

----> **Not possible on developer console** but you can schedule a job on your own server to fetch data

3) Is it possible to pull out the stack trace specified in the "Crash Link" field of the report using the gsutil utility?

-> **Yes**

Comment: Amod, can you provide an example of the gsutil command with which you can download the stack trace from the crash link?

Comment: OK, I see in the description how to download the report. But how through gsutil to open the link which is indicated in Crash Link there is not described, and the question is how to open a link from Crash Link without using Google Play Console Developer.